# Is it optimal to fill in missing values with zeros in neural network models?

Tags: neural-network, missing-data, imputation

My question is specifically for Neural Network models and for substitution with some specific value (not mean, median or prediction-based imputation): If the data set contains nulls/Nans, is the optimal imputation the number 0 (zero)? Or should it be some other number (like -999 for example) which is NOT already contained in the dataset? Or will it make no difference in the end? I ask because I think that if we fill in with a value that already exists in our data it is like cancelling out the information contained in that variable. Am I missing something?